# mysql select lowest price from multi select

Tags: mysql, select

TABLE price

```
user_id    b01    b02    b03    b04    b05    b06    b07    b08    b09
MP01       21     32     12     34     56     26     21     21     26    
MO11       81     332    112    1      12     22     71     17     23
```

How to SELECT lowest price FROM price WHERE user_id = 'MP01' ?

example for user_id   MP01, to get the result 12

Comment: shouldn't the lowest price be be 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the LEAST function, as in:

`select least(b01,b02,b03,b04,b05,b06,b07,b08,b09) from price where user_id = 'MP01'`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least

Answer (score 2):

Base on your example i think you mean the result is 12. If that is the case you can do

```
SELECT LEAST(b01, b02, b03, b04, b05, b06, b07, b08, b09) FROM price WHERE user_id = 'MP01'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach to LEAST. Not easy as Using Least function. But might come in handy in some situations

```
SELECT MIN(b01) FROM(
select user_id , b01 from price
union all
select user_id , b02 from price
union all
select user_id , b03 from price
union all
select user_id , b04 from price
union all
select user_id , b05 from price
union all
select user_id , b06 from price
union all
select user_id , b07 from price
union all
select user_id , b08 from price
union all
select user_id , b09 from price
) temp 
WHERE user_id = 'MP01'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `least`

```
select least(b01,b02,b03,b04,b05,b06,b07,b08,b09)
FROM Table1
where user_id='MP01'
```